# Modifying a Cell<NonNull<T>> through multiple owners - UB or not?

Tags: rust

I'm toying around with a smaller version of `Rc` which stores the reference-count in the pointer, utilizing the unused bits due to alignment. *I suspect I'm causing UB, but I'm wondering where exactly and why.*

Most basically this looks like

```
struct SmallRc<T> {
    inner: Cell<NonNull<T>>
}
```

The constructor allocates for `T` and stores it at the pointer.

The impl of `Clone` looks - very roughly - like

```
fn clone(&self) -> Self {
    // Overflow-check within alignment-bits not shown
    let cur = self.inner.get().as_ptr() as usize;
    self.inner.set(unsafe { NonNull::new_unchecked((cur + 1) as *mut T) });
    Self {
        // This is where a new owner is created
        // so there are now multiple owners of the same pointer
        inner: self.inner.clone()
    }
}
```

The `Drop`-impl looks almost identical, again paraphrased:

```
impl<T> Drop for SmallRc<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        // decrement the reference-counter similar as to how Clone does it.
        self.dec_strong_count(); 
        if self.strong_count() == 0 {
             // drop and deallocate the inner value
        }
    }
}
```

The `Deref`-impl masks the pointer and dereferences it. In essence, there is never more than one `&mut T` active; the pointer is never used in un-aligned form; `cargo miri test` passes.

All this works to some extent. However, the following test fails

```
let rc = SmallRc::new(5u32);
assert_eq!(SmallRc::capacity(&rc), 3);
assert_eq!(SmallRc::strong_count(&rc), 1);
assert_eq!(*rc, 5);
let rc2 = rc.clone();
assert_eq!(SmallRc::strong_count(&rc), 2);
assert_eq!(SmallRc::strong_count(&rc2), 2);
assert_eq!(*rc2, 5);
drop(rc2);
assert_eq!(SmallRc::strong_count(&rc), 1);  // Fails, reference count is still 2.
```

Tracing this reveals that while the `Drop`-impl decrements the reference count and stores the new pointer in the `Cell`, the last call to `strong_count` uses the same (old) value without reading from the `Cell` at all.

I'm wondering why, exactly, this is. Especially since the implementation of `std::rc` is roughly similar; the difference being that the reference count is in a `Cell` *behind* a pointer while here we have a `Cell` *for* the pointer.

Comment: Just to be annoying, have you tested the reference count is correct before cloning?

Comment: Didn't show, but yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cell`s and related types (like `RefCell` or `UnsafeCell`) in Rust are *not* pointers, they are just wrappers that provide interior mutability. So every single `SmallRc` value will have its own `Cell` value, each with its own `NonNull` pointer. Changing that pointer of one `SmallRc` value will not affect the others because they do not share data.

`std::rc::Rc` on the other hand has a pointer to a reference-counting structure (`NonNull<RcBox<T>>`). The pointer itself never changes, but the `Rc` values can point to the same reference-counting structure, so changing the reference count in that will affect all other `Rc` values pointing to the same structure.

I'm imagining your `SmallRc` would behave something like this (notice how `clone` and `drop` only affect the values they work with directly):

```rust
let rc = SmallRc::new(5u32);
// rc = { 0x12340001 } // <-- example pointer values
let rc2 = rc.clone();
// rc = { 0x12340002 }, rc2 = { 0x12340002 }
let rc3 = rc2.clone();
// rc = { 0x12340002 }, rc2 = { 0x12340003 }, rc3 = { 0x12340003 }
drop(rc2)
// rc = { 0x12340002 }, rc2 = [dropped], rc3 = { 0x12340003 }
```

Comment: Meh, obviously yes. The reference count is increased on `rc1`, from that point on everybody works on their own copy of the pointer. I guess I can make this work using `Pin` and have every clone keep a reference to where the original pointer is living.